# Domain specific language IDE

Tags: ide, editor, bison, flex-lexer

I've recently developed a domain-specific language using flex and bison. I would like to create a user interface for editing script files using this language. In particular I would like to have common functionalities such as file handling, menus, buttons, syntax highlighting, error checking and so on. Do you know any tool which can be used to develop such kind of application? I would prefer one which can give me a prototype rapidly.

Comment: Modern editors can be configured with syntax highlighting and auto completion for custom languages.  Have you considered just building on top of an existing editor?

Comment: Could you please give me an example of such editor? I know there are many editors out there, but I don't know which one I can use to do this. @Josh

Comment: I primarily use vim.  For syntax highlighting, you just need to create a single file (see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files).  Custom shortcuts and file handling options can be set in your .vimrc file, as well as adding additional vim scripts.  You can pretty easily achieve all the goals you have listed, except for error checking.  If that's a selling point, you probably could use eclipse. You'd just have to create some glue-code between your compiler/interpreter and eclipse's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> such as file handling, menus, buttons, syntax highlighting, **error
>   checking**

I think that file handling, menus, buttons and highlighting are your least concerns. What you  call "error checking" on the other hand. That can be a tough nut. I will try to give you some pointers to how you can (in a somewhat primitive manner) detect errors on the fly as the user inputs source code in the editor.

I assume you wish for something like Eclipses (for java at least) real time analysis of the written code in the editor? I'm not familiar with how Eclipse work internally but this is probably done by some pre-compilation process that processes all source code again and again as you change it.

One way to prototype this (and indeed build a non-prototype as well) would be to use Flex and Bison, and I notice you already is familiar with these tools. You can build you grammar and create action code for all interesting parts so you can find syntax deviations fairly easy. After this you make your editor run the flex and bison generated c-code as the user writes the source code in you IDE and have some way of displaying the output. Either in a terminal-like status window or directly in the text-editing field (as Eclipse does) (the latter case is probably a pain to build but by no means impossible and would give you IDE a professional touch).

Suppose you would like to build an IDE for ADA 95 the following Flex and Bison (Actually Lex and Yacc) code could help you do exactly this (it's a decent syntax analyzer that reports errors (what and where)):
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/lexer9x.l
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/grammar9x.y

Hope this helps.

Edit:
to have cool error highlighting and such in the text-editor field of your IDE you could let your bison generated syntax analyser generate something thats easy to parse, like XML, that contains the type of error and where it lies (row and column for example) and then use that to display the errors... you simply embed an XML parser in the IDE (lots of free one available) and extract the data you need and change the display accordingly... That shouldn't be rocket science when I think about it.